# What is URL for sustainsys.saml2 generated metadata?

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

Im using the sustainsys.saml2 library in an MVC application. Ive been asked to provide the metadata for my service provider(SP) application. Does the sustainsys library do this for me? What is the URL i would give the IDP for my application metadata?

The sustainsys help documentation for the web.config  element says:

> The metadata part of the configuration can be used to tweak the
>   generated metadata. These configuration options only affect how the
>   metadata is generated, no other behavior of the code is changed.

Again, what is the URL for this generated metadata ?  I am happy to give more information.... I just dont know what i dont know at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The metadata is exposed at https://yourapp.com/Saml2. If you've set the `ModulePath` property, the path is changed.

Comment: It was too simple i missed it! Thank you. Works perfect. I think i missed this because to get this to work I had to enable the MVC route in my RouteConfig.cs:           `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Saml2meta",
                url: "Saml2",
                defaults: new { controller = "Saml2", action = "Index" }
            );`